# How to delete facebook parameters that puts the url's shared on your wall in codeigniter links

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

When I share a link http://www.totalrunning.com/results/misFotos/TTRCAR1346364033/283 (Codeigniter Url's) on my Facebook wall appears fine but when clicking the resulting URL is: http://www.totalrunning.com/results/misFotos/TTRCAR1346364033/283?fb_action_ids=441641579216005&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582

fb_action_ids added among other parameters this causes the url not resolving correctly

That I can do to make facebook not put those parameters in my url or like handling with Codeigniter ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was through the same file using Codeigniter .htaccess to hide the index.php

Above this htaccess put the following:

```
# -----------------
RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} ^ fb_action_ids = (. *) $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ / $ 1? [R = 301, L]
# -----------------
```

with this code you tell the server that elime the query string of the url but only when he comes fb_action_ids or any parameter you choose not prevent the proper functioning of query strings in CodeIgniter

With this you can preserves the beautiful codeigniter urls and facebook links resolved correctly!

Important: Put it up to avoid file overwrite functionality to hide the index.php

Answer (score 0):

### Enabling Query Strings

In some cases you might prefer to use query strings URLs:

```
index.php?c=products&m=view&id=345
```

CodeIgniter optionally supports this capability, which can be enabled in your application/config.php file. If you open your config file you'll see these items:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
```

If you change `enable_query_strings` to `TRUE` this feature will become active. Your controllers and functions will then be accessible using the "trigger" words you've set to invoke your controllers and methods:

```
index.php?c=controller&m=method
```

You can read more at the Code Ignitor user-guide here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: for marketing reasons I can not use query strings in URLs I need is to delete or ignore these parameters because facebook puts but I do not need

Comment: You could strip them off server side using .htaccess http://briancray.com/posts/htaccess-hack-remove-url-query-strings/

Comment: Thank you. this article was very useful to solve my problem just needed rewriting rules to restrict the url because that behavior is not always needed. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this method. Just add a slash after your final parameter and it will work fine. It will ignore all those facebook extras